# Implementing Camera Movement and Rotation in 3D Game Engine

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, projection, projection-matrix

Apologies in advance for any mistakes on terminology, I'm really really new to this

I'm completely new to 3d (and it's maths) but as a personal exercise I'm doing my own game engine that displays a simple wireframe.

I've implemented rotate (x, y and z), orthogonal, isometric, perspective projection matrices (column major) and a look_at function.

I've got a list of points and my rudimentary pipeline (on keypress) is as follows:

1. get original points
2. scale
3. rotate_x
4. rotate_y
5. rotate_z
6. look_at(cam,target,up)
7. projection
8. translate to centre of the window
   It works fine with hardcoded camera and target coordinates

However I want to be able to:

1. move the camera up/down/left/right in the same plane I'm currently at.
2. To be able to rotate that plane around the z axis
3. and to bring the plane the camera is closer or farther from the z axis
   But I have no Idea how to do that. (quaternions or matrices)

The reason I want to rotate around the z axis and not the y is because I haven't implemented any coordinate system and the hardcoded camera and target values are for an isometric projection.

How can I do this?

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) and all sublinks in there especially those at the end ...

Comment: @Spektre Thanks! I see that you are well versed in this could you help me out with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76855554/warp-curve-all-vertices-around-a-pivot-point-axis) please?