# Warp / curve all vertices around a pivot point / axis

Tags: python, c++, math, 3d, projection

I'm trying to work out how to warp all coordinates in a simple Python Game Engine I made around a specific pivot point / axis. The best way to describe it is as if I was to place a tube somewhere in the scene and everything else in the scene would curve around that axis and keep the same distance from that axis.

If it helps, this diagram is what I'm trying to achieve. The top part is as if you were looking at the scene from the side and the bottom part is as if you were looking at it from a perspective. The red dot / line is where the pivot point is.

[image: Warp around a pivot point]

To further complicate matters, I'd like to stop the curve / warp from wrapping back on itself, so the curve stops when it's horizontal or vertical like the top-right example in the diagram.

Any insight into how to achieve this using just matrices or just math?

I'm also open to alternative approaches to this as I'm unsure how best to describe what I'm after. Basically I want an inverted "curved world" effect where the scene is bending up and away from you.

[image: Curved world in Unity]

Comment: looks verry similar to this: [How to bend a cylinder in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050883/2521214)